# What does these words "an underlying condition" mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

I am reading this article:
https://www.healthline.com/health/botox-poison#safety

> ..  of adverse effects associated with cosmetic use were reported to
> the U. S. Food and Drug Administration (FDA) between 1989 and 2003.
> Thirteen of these cases may have had more to do with an underlying
> condition than with the drug itself. ..

What is an "underlying condition" here?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/underlying. It means there may be more to the cause apart from the drugs themselves.

Comment: Have you tried Googling for “what is an underlying condition”? After doing so and reading a few of the relevant-looking articles, what do you still not understand?

Comment: It means the same thing in all cases of its being used...

Comment: @MikeScott Thanks for the hint. I did try to search underlying at first. Now I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In medicine, an "underlying condition" is a pre-existing medical condition that contributes to an outcome. A condition is referred to as "underlying" when is not the immediate focus of the study or treatment.

> Example:
> Two people are exposed to identical levels of gas. The gas is not poisonous at these levels, but one of the two people dies because they had an existing respiratory condition which meant they could not cope with the lack of oxygen the exposure caused. This person died, not because of the exposure, but because of their *underlying condition*.

In your example, some people experienced adverse effects after using cosmetics, but the effects were linked to underlying conditions. They were underlying because the focus of the study was the direct effects of the cosmetics.